# Getting Swedish Apple keyboard to map the same way in Bootcamp (Windows 7)

Tags: keyboard, macos, bootcamp, windows

Whenever I use Windows 7 through Bootcamp, my keyboard mappings are totally different. Many special keys get mapped to what they would be on a PC keyboard, which is a real pain since I program on both platforms (and I am mostly used to the mac layout). The problem characters are these: []{}|\

On my SE Mac keyboard, I use these combinations:

- [] - any alt + 8/9
- {} - any alt + shift + 8/9
- | - any alt + 7
- \ - any alt + shift + 7

When in Bootcamp, it behaves like a Swedish PC keyboard:

- [] - right alt + 8/9
- {} - right alt + 7/0
- | - right alt + >
- \ - right alt + ?

I have tried numerous keyboard settings without any difference.
I was able to switch control and command using a register key but I have found no way to switch the combinations above.

Is there any way to fix this?

As I understand it, US keyboards  do not have this problem since the above keys maps the same way on Mac and PC keyboards. I really envy that...

Comment: Normally to get what you want you need to create a Windows layout with the Apple mapping (unless you see one in the Windows settings called Swedish Apple).  The tool for making such things is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx

Comment: @TomGewecke Yeah, thanks. I've seen that tool before but was unable to map left alt and left alt+shift as shift states (I use left alt for all the special chars on mac). However, I tried it again now and instead mapped with alt-gr (right alt). Then I used SharpKeys to switch left alt and right alt. Not so pretty but it actually works. Only downside is that shortcuts such as alt-tab now use the right alt key. But I guess I can live with that. At least I can write code like a normal person now! Btw, there is a Swedish Apple layout, but it maps just like a PC keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably get what you want by creating a Windows layout with the Apple mapping. The tool for making such things is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx